# Regex for phone # country code with area code

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need a regex to match this country-code + area code phone # format:

```
1-201
```

where the first two characters are always `1-` and the last 3 characters are digits between `201` and `989`.

I have `([1][\-][0-9]{3})` currently to specify the `1-xyz` and limit length but how can I have the last group to restrict those ranges?

This will be used in PHP.

Comment: This is rather tricky.  RegEx isn't always the best answer, especially for the poor soul that needs to maintain the code in 3 years.  However, it can be done http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: Just because you have regexes doesn't mean you should use them. A regex here will be hard to read and will get thrown out the first time somebody else has to update it.

Comment: I disagree with that in my case. Using regex to validate phone number formats is fairly common from what I've seen and plugging this into a tester can easily identify what is going on. I'm a regex idiot and I understand it perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^1\-(2\d[1-9])|([3-8]\d{2})|(9[0-8]\d)$
```

Here is an explanation of the three capturing groups/ranges:

`(2\d[1-9])` matches `201` to `299`
`([3-8]\d{2})` matches `300` to `899`
`(9[0-8]\d)` matches `900` to `989`

Here is a link where you can test this regex:

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/yF2oT1/1)

**Update:**

Apparently Laravel doesn't like having so many nested capture groups, but this simplification should work for your needs:

```
1-(2\d[1-9]|[3-8]\d{2}|9[0-8]\d)
```

Comment: It's very odd, actually it validates perfectly on the test site but for some reason using this to validate a route in my Laravel app doesn't work on the 2nd and 3rd subexpressions - it fails as if the string just doesn't match.

Comment: Try using this: `1-(2\d[1-9]|[3-8]\d{2}|9[0-8]\d)`

Comment: OK then it seems Laravel is choking on too many nested capture groups.  I just learned something :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a regex for this. It is going to be messy and hard to maintain.

I would do something like this:

```
$strings = array('1-201', '1-298', '1-989', '1-999', '1-200');
foreach($strings as $string) {
    $value = explode('1-', $string);
    if($value[1] >= 201 & $value[1] <= 989) {
        echo 'In range' . $string  . "\n";
    } else {
        echo 'out of range' . $string . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
In range1-201
In range1-298
In range1-989
out of range1-999
out of range1-200
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
1-(20[1-9]|2[1-9][0-9]|[3-8][0-9][0-9]|9[0-8][0-9])
```

Alternately,

```
1-(20[1-9]|2[1-9]\d|[3-8]\d{2}|9[0-8]\d)
```

source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: While @Tim Biegeleisen's answer validates, only this one works in my Laravel 5 app for some reason...

Comment: I studied DarkSigma's regex and improved my knowledge.

Comment: The regex supplied by @Tim will not match on 210, 220, 230, etc. until and including 290, because `2\d[1-9]` only allows the numbers 1 through 9 in the "one's column", not zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do it like the following in C#. Experimented.

```
string tester = "1-201";

Match match = Regex.Match(tester, @"(?<one>1-)(?<Two>[0-9]{3})");

//MessageBox.Show(match.Groups[2].Value);

int x = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);

if (x <= 201 && x > 989)
{
    //Exclude those captures not necessary.
    //Use the captures within the range.
}
```

Comment: But my App is for PHP.

Comment: You only have to get the equivalent regex in PHP and code the rest. A search will prove useful to you.